# Android: Monitor network traffic of apps, using similar tool to F12->Network on Web

Tags: android, adb

In Web development it's well known that inside the Dev console->Network tab it's possible to read, for example, Json's traffic between the client and server.

What about similar tool for Android apps? Is something like this  achievable: Connecting device on debug mode to ADB, and see the web traffic? For example to read in live how App X receiving Json from her back-end server? (And similar to Web - Read this Json...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Debugging Proxy like Charles: http://www.charlesproxy.com/
This is in my opinion the best option for network inspection because it gives you a lot of advanced options such as:

- Replaying requests
- Simulating slow network speed
- Setting up breakpoints where you can edit the response from the server before it hits your app

The only downside is that it can be a little tedious to set up, and you have to edit your phone/emulator Wifi settings a lot...

You can also add a debugging library to your app, like Stetho by Facebook: http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

This will let you observe the network requests made by your app in the Chrome Dev Tools amongst other thing (inspecting your layouts on screen, read/write DB and Shared Preferences access...)

Comment: Thanks, What about "official" android solution? The regular ADB not support's this? And if so - Why?

Comment: There is to my knowledge no official ADB support for this, and given that Charles seems to be the de-facto choice for this being widely adopted and does a very good job, I don't think it would make sense for the Android tools team to work on something like this at the moment

Answer (score 1):

try this tool called charles proxy. We use it all the time at work and works like a charm. http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Thanks, let's say in my device some popular app is running and clearly they use not encrypted or anything like this Json's. If I now connect my device to it - I'll be able to read the content of these Json's?

Comment: yup basically all your internet packages will be redirected through this proxy. You will have to be on the same wifi network.